# Why does adding nodes in (reverse) order make for inefficient searching?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am preparing for an exam and I have stumbled on the following question:

> Draw the binary search tree that would result if data were to be added in the following order:
>
> `10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3`
>
> Why is the tree that results unsuitable for efficient searching?

My Answer:

I would have thought when creating a BST that we start with the value 10 as the root node then add 9 as the left sub tree value on the first level. Then 8 to the left subtree of 9 and so on. I don't know why this makes it inefficient for searching though. Any ideas?

Comment: It can be efficient if the tree is self-balancing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the values are in decreasing order, they get added to the left at each level, practically leaving you with a linked list, which takes O(N) to search, instead of the preferred O(logN) of a BST.

Drawing:

```
              10
             /
            9
           /
          8
         /
        7
       /
      6
     /
    5
   /
  4
 /
3
```

Comment: +1 for the drawing. A picture says a thousand words, even if it's ASCII art :)

Comment: +1 and drawing shows the effort put to answer the question! Nice!

Answer (score 0):

This would create a linked-list, since it would just be a series of nodes; which is a heavily unbalanced tree.

You should look up [red-black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). They have the same time-complexities, but it will constantly move around nodes, so that it is always forming a triangular shape. This will keep the tree balanced.

Answer (score 0):

This is inefficient because the node will always be added to the left subtree of the prior node.  Making a search check every every node in the list until it finds the result even though the answer will always be to the left thus actually making it take more computations than just simply having a list that is searched through a loop.